# how to do spectrum analyse with FFTW?

Tags: c++, c, fftw, spectrum

I would like to better understand FFTW's API. FFTW is a library for computing the discrete Fourier transform (DFT) in one or more dimensions.

Now, assume I have a sinus waveform  x=30*sin(2*M_PI*f*i*T), where f is the frequency (for example f=1000Hz).
 If I use FFTW's function to analyse my waveform, I expect to get one frequency f=1000Hz.

My question is how can I do this in c++ using FFTW Library?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find more details in [FFTW's documentation](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/).

However, for the relatively simple case of one-dimensional real-valued signal, the following is a sum-up of the general steps you have to do.

Typically you would need to allocate input/output buffers, and a data-structure which FFTW uses for its own bookkeeping which the library refers as a `plan`. This can be done in a number of ways (more details in FFTW's documentation), such as:

```
  #include "fftw3.h"

  // First choose a buffer size:
  //   Typically best performance with a power of 2
  //   but could be a product of small primes
  int           input_size    = 1024; 
  //   Compute corresponding number of complex output samples
  int           output_size   = (input_size/2 + 1);

  // Allocate input and output buffers
  double*       input_buffer  = static_cast<double*      >(fftw_malloc(input_size  * sizeof(double)));
  fftw_complex* output_buffer = static_cast<fftw_complex*>(fftw_malloc(output_size * sizeof(fftw_complex)));

  // Create plan
  //   Select plan creation flags
  //   see http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html#Planner-Flags
  int           flags = FFTW_ESTIMATE;
  fftw_plan     plan = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(input_size, 
                                            input_buffer, 
                                            output_buffer, 
                                            flags);
```

Once that is done, you can fill in the `input_buffer` with the real-valued data samples to analyse, and perform the FFT using:

```
 fftw_execute(plan);
```

The complex-valued results will be stored in `output_buffer`, where `output_buffer[0]` corresponds to a frequency of 0, and `output_buffer[output_size-1]` corresponds to half the sampling rate. This plan can be executed multiple times (with updated values in `input_buffer`, resulting in correspondingly updated values in `output_buffer`).

Note that typically `fftw_complex` (which is the datatype used for the output in this example) is implemented as an array of 2 values: index 0 corresponds to the real-part, and index 1 corresponds to the imaginary-part (e.g. `output_buffer[i][0]` corresponds to the real-part of the i<sup>th</sup> frequency component).

Once you are done, you can release allocated resources with:

```
  fftw_free(input_buffer);
  fftw_free(output_buffer);
  fftw_destroy_plan(plan);
```

Note that if you may use `float`, `double` or `long double` versions of those functions. Simply link against the corresponding `libfftw3f-3.lib`, `libfftw3-3.lib` or `libfftw3l-3.lib`.

**Update**: If you want to use complex-valued input samples together with `fftw_plan_dft_1d`, you will then have to set the real and imaginary parts like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < N-1; ++i) {
  t[i]=i*T;
  signal[i][0] = 0.7 * sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]); // real-part
  signal[i][1] = 0.0; // imaginary-part
}
```

Alternatively change the input sample type to `float`, `double` or `long double` (together with using `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d`).

Answer (score 0):

your question falls to the category [One-Dimensional DFTs of Real Data](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#One_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data)

step1: generate waveform data respecting to the frequency 1000hz by the function you provided `x = 30(2*pi*1000*id` (make sure the sample freq is 2 times 2*f which is 2000, I suggest you iterate id by range（0,1,1/2000）) which gives you 2000 sample data.

step2: use the function to get the dft output

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(int n, double *in, fftw_complex *out,
                                    unsigned flags);
```